# how to get a valid file url with collectionFS on meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to do a quite simple app on how to use CollectionFS new API (a kind of proof of concept). 
It seems I succeed to store image on server, but in fact I fail to get a valid URL.

I use the method `url(`) on an `fsFile` object. It returns a URL, but when I test it in my browser, nothing happens. I tried to use `FS.HTTP.mount()` but it still fails.

I'm doing something wrong for sure, but what?

You can have a try at the app here:

https://github.com/Rebolon/meteor-tuto-gridfs.git

Answer (score 0):

URL format is:

```
/cfs/files/{fs_collection_name}/{fs_file_id}
```

For your code, url would be:

```
/cfs/files/cfstest_images/{fs_file_id}
```